# Line entity Processor

Tags: solr

My requirement is to search inside a file content and if the word is present it has to send the particular line of the file content where the word is present. I have used Solr-DIH and for processing line by line I am using Line entity Processor. My data-config file is

```
    <dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" name = "fds"/>
    <document>
    <entity name="filelist" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" fileName="sample.docx"
      rootEntity="false"   baseDir="C:\SampleDocuments" >
    <entity name="fileline" processor="LineEntityProcessor"
            url="${filelist.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">                   
            <field column="linecontent" name="rawLine"/>
    </entity>
    </entity>
    </document>
```

The schema.xml is having entry or rawLine.

```
    <field name="rawLine"  type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I am able to do a full-import but even if there are only 3 lines in the document its creating around 52 documents and if i am searching for a content thats already present in the document, the resonse is still 0. Please help me on this as I am not able to find much information on line entity processor.

**Edit 1** field-type `text`

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/> 
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" 
            splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Could you give a bit of your sample file and the declaration of your type `text` that is inplace for your field `rawLine`?

Comment: My sample is having just some data like                                     sample document                                                         sample text

Comment: My text data type is as shown 
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

Comment: <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to import a `Microsoft Word` file. I can see this from your dataconfig: `fileName="sample.docx"`.

You cannot do this with the `FileListEntityProcessor`. This one is intended for ASCII files. But Word is a binary file format. You need to use an `ExtractingRequestHandler` for this cause.

As a starting point take [Lucid's documentation](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika) or [search here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=solr%20ExtractingRequestHandler).

In order to display only a small portion of the document where the keywords produced a hit use the `Highlighting` feature of Solr.

You can find several resources on the web, how Highlighting works

- in [the Highlighting chapter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting) of Lucid's reference documentation
- in [this article about Highlighting in conjunction with Tika](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/highlight-matched-text-solr)
- here [in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsolr%5D%20highlighting)

Comment: When I am using the same schema and data-config by replacing the LineEntityProcessor with TikaEntityProcessor and rawLine into 'Text', I am able to do the search properly and retrieve the file contents. But the problem is  its showing the enire contents. Bt what I require is only the line where the query word is present. (similar to google search results.)

Comment: Thanks for your response @SushaSurendran I have updated my response for your problem.

Comment: thanks for the response.... I am able to solve my problem using highlighting feature.